# Moment JS - UTC to Local timestamp fails comparison

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, momentjs, utc

**When converting a UTC date format to timestamp this condition will always fail**

```
const start_time = "2017-03-02T15:57:00Z";
const stop_time = "2017-03-02T17:51:00Z";
const local_timestamp = 1488498242256; // Thu Mar 02 2017 16:44:02 GMT-0700 (MST)

const start = moment(start_time).valueOf(); // 1488470220000
const stop = moment(stop_time).valueOf(); // 1488477060000

const is_between = local_timestamp >= start && local_timestamp <= stop; // false
```

**So I tried this and still failed**

```
const start = moment(start_time).utc().valueOf(); // 1488470220000
const stop = moment(stop_time).utc().valueOf(); // 1488477060000
const is_between = local_timestamp >= start && local_timestamp <= stop; // false
```

**Same thing here**

```
const now = moment(local_timestamp);
const isBetween =  now.isBetween(start, stop); // false
```

**Please help me understand this.**

Answer (score 2):

> When converting a UTC date format to timestamp this condition will always fail

A [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) is anything that represents a date or time, so "2017-03-02T15:57:00Z", "Thu Mar 02 2017 16:44:02 GMT-0700 (MST)" and 1488498242256 are all timestamps.

1488498242256 represents "2017-03-02T23:44:02.256Z" which is not between "2017-03-02T15:57:00Z" and "2017-03-02T17:51:00Z", so the expected result of your tests is false.

> So I tried this and still failed

It's not failing, it's returning the expected result.

When you do, say:

```
new Date(1488498242256)
```

then a Date instance is created with a time value of 1488498242256, which represents "2017-03-02T23:44:02.256Z". When you write this to output that generates a string, usually *Date.prototype.toString* is called and a string is generated in what the browser developers have determined is a human friendly format.

Typically this means that the host system timezone offset is used to generate the string and you see something like:

```
"Thu Mar 02 2017 16:44:02 GMT-0700 (MST)"
```

On SO, the console seems to use *toISOString* instead of the default *toString*, e.g.

```js
var date = new Date(1488498242256);

// Standard output for the host environment
console.log(date);

// Call Date.prototype.toString specifically
console.log(date.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know what timestamps are :D I ended up fixing this issue by converting the local timestamp to a UTC offset timestamp by using **moment.utc(local_timestamp)**     But yeah thanks for your time. And hopefully your response will be useful many devs

Answer (score 1):

If start and end are UTC times, then use `moment.utc(start_time)` and `moment.utc(stop_time)`

But it doesn't seem logical to compare UTC dates against a local date. That is what it looks like you are attempting.

Comment: You are right comparing UTC times against local times is not logical. In htis case I was getting different results from the back end. What happened is that the backend service could not give me the UTC timestamp so it would fall back to the machine local time. Thanks again for your response

Comment: Yeah, dates are always a pain.  In that case you might also try using [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) for easier conversions.